# Grid in a Grid with RowDefinition Height="auto" suppresses Height="*" of child Grid's RowDefinitions

Tags: wpf

I have the following code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" TextBlock.Foreground="Blue" ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="test" Grid.Row="0" />
        <TextBlock Text="test" Grid.Row="2" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" TextBlock.Foreground="Red" ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="test" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="test" Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

It's simply two equal grids with three rows, all three which should be of equal size (each in its own grid, that is).

The bottom grid, contained in the parent row with a height of "*" behaves as expected. Each row is of equal size, regardless of what is put into it.

But the top grid, contained in a row with height Auto, seems to discard the Height="*", and behave as if they had Height="Auto". The first and third row gets exactly the height they ask for, and the second, the empty row, is just given a height of 0. Is this normal behaviour? And if so, why is it the way it is?

This is how it appears:
[image]

And this is how I would expect it to work:
[image]

Comment: The top grid doesn't discard the `* Width` markup, it actually uses it! Why you can see it as being `Auto` is because the `PARENT` grid is allowing only `Auto`. Therefore your inner grid is using * width of auto height of parent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour is expected. `Height="*"` means that all rows will share evenly available space

> The value is expressed as a weighted proportion of available space

When you set parent row height to auto it means that child `Grid` is not stretched vertically any more so there is no free space to share so rows will take only as much space as they need to. It's like you would set `VerticalAlignment="Top"` for example.

You can achieve what you want by using [`SharedSizeGroup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup(v=vs.110).aspx) on the top `Grid`. In this scenario all rows belong to the same group and all will share same height

```xml
<Grid Grid.Row="0" IsSharedSizeScope="True" TextBlock.Foreground="Blue" ShowGridLines="True" >
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommonRow"/>
      <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommonRow"/>
      <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="CommonRow"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <TextBlock Text="test" Grid.Row="0" />
   <TextBlock Text="test" Grid.Row="2" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Ah, so it's implemented differently than I would have expected. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Not in these exact words but it's consistent with what I would expect from `Grid` which is not vertically stretched. It's how it works.

Answer (score 2):

it behaves is normally.
when you set `Height="*"` that means **fill the rest of space,** 
while `Height="Auto"` means **fit to all inner controls**.
 so the first row is fitting all the controls that you have which they are only two, and because there is no `Height` property set to first inner grid or TextBlocks it takes only the height that equal `yourFirstTextBlock.Height + yourSecondTextBlock.Height`.